# Rails form validates with custom method only if any value is provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I have a conditional form field (which is shown by clicking a checkbox) which I want to validate with a custom method.

```
validates :number, length: { maximum: 20 }, if: :checksum_is_valid?

def checksum_is_valid?
  if !Luhn.valid?(number)
    errors.add(number, "is not valid.")
  end
end
```

is my attempt. This technically works fine but the error is also shown, even if I don't enter any number at all (because the field is not mandatory). Any idea how I can check with a custom method, but only if the user provides any number at all.

Thanks

Comment: could you add more context, like what does Luhn do? How is the code used? a successful and an unsuccessful attempt

Comment: @Mhmd as I said it all works fine. The problem is that I don't know how to only fire `checksum_is_valid?` if an actual value is entered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`validate`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) instead of `validates` for custom validators and then move the check if there is a number present into the validator method:

```
validate :checksum_valid?

private
def checksum_valid?
  if number.present?
    errors.add(:number, "is not valid.") unless number_valid?
  end
end

def number_valid?
  number.length < 20 && Luhn.valid?(number)
end
```

Comment: this is pretty much it, but I also need to check if the number is `< 20`

Comment: just a little thing to mention is, that I needed `number.length` because it is a string

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing two things in your code, so let me help you understanding better what is happening.

1). conditional validation:

```
validates :number, length: { maximum: 20 }, if: :checksum_is_valid?
```

By this, Rails expects the model to implement method `checksum_is_valid?` which returns boolean value, based on which it will perform this validation. Something like would work:

```
def checksum_is_valid?
  Luhn.valid?(number)
end
```

In case this method returns `true`, Rails would perform the validation of `:number` is not more than `20`.

2). custom validation:

When using this custom method, you can build your own validation logic and error. So, if you have your method:

```
def checksum_is_valid?
  if !Luhn.valid?(number)
    errors.add(number, "is not valid.")
  end
end
```

You should configure your validator with:

```
validate :checksum_valid?
```

Unfortunately, from your code is not clear what you would like to achieve (validate the number not to be more than 20, or perform the custom validator), but I hope what I've pointed will help you make the proper decision how to take that further.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for this in detail answer. You kind of get what I mean. I had it exactly like you explain in your answer, with the difference that I also wanna make sure that the number is maximum 20 chars. Fair enough thats easy to add. But now comes the problem, how can I ensure that it does not validate if no number is provided. When doing `validates :number, length: { maximum: 20 }` it only checks this if a value is provided.

Comment: There is third option you could try - perform both validations in custom method. What about - `validate :number_valid?`, and in custom method you could implement it similarly to: `def number_valid? if number errors.add(:number, "is not valid.") unless Luhn.valid?(number) && number < 20 end end`. I can't suggest better solution as I don't know enough how those would play in your domain, what other validations you have, and what plans for future you have. I hope to at least put you in proper direction!